# NoSQL database and many semi-large blobs

Tags: nosql, scalability, blob, key-value-store

Is there a NoSQL (or other type of) database suitable for storing a large number (i.e. >1 billion) of "medium-sized" blobs (i.e. 20 KB to 2 MB). All I need is a mapping from A (an identifier) to B (a blob), the ability to retrieve "B" given A, a consistent external API for access, and the ability to "just add another computer" to scale the system.

Something simpler than a database, e.g. a distributed key-value system, may just fine, and I'd appreciate any thoughts along that vein as well.

Thank you for reading.

Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your API requirements are purely along the lines of  "Get(key), Put(key,blob), Remove(key)" then a key-value store (or more accurately a "Persistent distributed hash table") is exactly what you are looking for.

There a quite a few of these available, but without additional information it is hard to make a solid recommendation - What OS are you targeting? Which language(s) are you developing with? What are the I/O characteristics of your app (cold/immutable data such as images? high write loads aka tweets?)

Some of the KV systems worth looking into:
- [MemcacheDB](http://memcachedb.org/)
- [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index.html)
- [Voldemort](http://project-voldemort.com/)

You may also want to look into document stores such as [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) or [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net)*. Document Stores are similar to KV stores but they understand the persistence format (usually JSON) so they can provide additional services such as indexing.

- If you are developing in .Net then skip directly to RavenDB (you'll thank me later)

Comment: Thanks, Addys - that's helpful. As for more info, here are the current targets: OS: Linux/BSD; Language: Python; I/O: write-once, read many.

Answer (score 1):

What about [Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/)?

> Apache Jackrabbit™ is a fully
>   conforming implementation of the
>   Content Repository for Java Technology
>   API (JCR, specified in JSR 170 and
>   283).
>
> A content repository is a hierarchical
>   content store with support for
>   structured and unstructured content,
>   full text search, versioning,
>   transactions, observation, and more.

I knew Jackrabbit when I worked with Liferay CMS. Liferay uses Jackrabbit to implement its [Document Library](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Document+Library+Portlet). It stores user files in the server's file system.

Answer (score 1):

You'll also want to take a look at [Riak](https://wiki.basho.com/display/RIAK/Riak). Riak is very focused on doing exactly what you're asking (just add node, easy to access).